# Using Spring profile and Maven Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-profiles

I am now to Spring profile and I have a question, if I am doing a environment specific build using maven like mvn -Ptest then do I need to provide SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE parameter on execution.

If I understand Spring Profile correctly, giving SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE will direct my spring boot application to pick up the necessary application properties/@profile beans then why do I need to do mvn -Ptest.

One point I came accross is that mvn -Ptest allows us to package our properties file accordingly but in that case, isnt using Spring Profile a better solution.

It will be great if someone can point any scenario wherein we have to use mvn -Ptest even if we are using spring profile in Java application.

Comment: Your build should never be environment dependant. The environments configurations can be handled with spring-boot profiles....

Comment: Okay, then what do I need different maven profiles for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing maven profiles with spring profiles.

Maven profiles allow you to execute builds with different build configurations. It is only used during the maven build process.

Spring profiles can allow you to load different property files and is available at runtime to do whatever you want.

Now, you may have a maven profile that executes your spring application with a spring profile set but the difference is build vs execution time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that....Can you give me any example which forces me to have multiple maven profiles given that I already have different spring profiles

Comment: Precompiling JSP files, minifying/compressing web resources, deploying to different environments, Fast builds vs Slow builds, etc.. Whatever you want to do. Simple projects may have no use for them but if you ever need to conditionally change you build profiles are there for you.